# html escaping, and how I may get owned

Tags: html, security, xss

I am planing to accept user input, and insert it inside a div

```
<div>user_content</div>
```

One user will provide the content, and the other will receive it.

The recommendation that I think I'll follow is from https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Element_Content

But I am very curious ... As far as I can tell, if I disallow the < and the >, that should prevent any insertion of scripts, or anything interesting, really

Hence, the question: How wrong am I ? What are the ways a malicious user can break my page/insert a script, given that < and > are escaped ? (and given that the text will be inserted inside a div)

Assume full generality: the malicious user might do weird things with encoding and such. But the page specifies its encoding as UTF-8

---

Please, note that the question is about escaping in a specific context: the user text goes inside a div. Not in an attribute, not in a script, not in CSS. What can go wrong with this naive escaping, PUTTING TEXT IN THIS SPECIFIC PLACE ?

Answer (score 1):

If you HTML encode the user input while *displaying* you should be safe. In this case, malicious code, for example a script tag, would simply display as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You are very wrong.

Escaping is context dependent. Just disallowing `<` and `>` results in a lot of broken things. For example:

## Unquoted Attributes

```
<a class={{var}}>
```

Imagine that `var` contains `foo onclick="alert('hi');"`

Boom, injected. But even if you escape quotes, you'll have weird attributes. So you need to be sure to **always** quote attributes.

## Script Context

```
<script>var a = "{{var}}";</script>
```

Imagine that `var` contains `"; alert('hi!'); "`. Boom, injected.

## CSS Context

```
<style>color = {{var}};</style>
```

Imagine there that `{{var}}` has `0;@import'http://....org/xss.css'`

Boom, the user imported their own stylesheet, which can append children and manipulate the body in significant ways.

## Conclusion

In short, follow the recommendations. Escape all appropriate characters in the appropriate contexts...

Comment: yup. That is why I said what was the context

Comment: I will follow the recommendations anyway. I just want to understand them from a security standpoint

Comment: @josinalvo yeah, completely get that. Just pointing out a few examples where "<>" don't give you security...

Comment: ok. Thanks. But... my question was: of I escape, and use the variable in that context, what can go wrong

Comment: You mentioned other contexts, but did not adress the context the question proposes

Answer (score 1):

Keep the rule of thumb: Do Not Trust What You Get From Users.
It's not necessarily < and >. 
To test this use firefox interceptor to bypass client side javascript validation, change text values to say for eg

```
"%3E%22%27%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%2830%29%3C%2Fscript%3E"
```

and send the request. If you are just checking for < and > then you might end up alerting in the face of your users.

Comment: what does this do ? How did you 'encode' the alert ?

Comment: if a user sends this to your server and with out any check if you try to display this content as part of you page it might show an alert box. The way to protect this (if you want to show user sent data) is to replace > by & lt; etc like: value = value.replaceAll("<", "& lt;").replaceAll(">", "& gt;");

Comment: ok. Maybe my question is a bit too basic ...
The thing I want to know is: how does this string with % and numbers converts to a string with <. Who does that ? The browser ?